# Best way to calculate dates from results?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, timestamp, date

I have a database table.  It has several hundred entries and each entry is timestamped.  I'm looking to only output each day and not have it duplicate any days.

Data:
2009-02-04 06:20:27
2009-02-04 06:20:27
2009-02-05 06:20:27
2009-02-07 06:20:27
2009-02-07 06:20:27
2009-02-07 06:20:27

Output should only be (time is irrelevant):
2009-02-04 06:20:27
2009-02-05 06:20:27
2009-02-07 06:20:27

What is the best way to accomplish this?  Should I really be cycling through each row and comparing one from another?  Just doesn't seem efficient.  Any ideas/tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to do this on the database level using the mysql DISTINCT keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date
FROM table
```

This will make it so if there are duplicate dates, only one is returned. Read more about it [here](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/sql/online_mysql_guide_the_distinct_keyword.php3).

Comment: Works but doesn't ignore time in the datetime field.

Comment: It works on the sample data because every entry has the same time value.  If there are any different time components, then it is going to yield the wrong results.

Answer (score 4):

can't you just select for a "DISTINCT" timestamp in your query?

Or if the times vary on each day (not sure from your example) you can convert the timestamp column to just a date of the fly using the mysql DATE function. Keep in mind this may prevent use of an index if it's used on that column.

eg.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(timestamp_column) FROM table
```

This will remove the time part of the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

This will print out double timestamps, but should be distinct to only the date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(timestamp AS DATE), timestamp, FROM table.
```

Comment: I always forget about the cast keyword.

Comment: The distinct qualifies the entire select list - so including the separate timestamp column yields the wrong answer if there are any different time values in any of the timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(data AS DATE)
    FROM DataTable;
```

This drops the time portion, and then gives the unique DATE values.

Answer (score 0):

The DATE() Function will extract the date from a datetime field. You can use the result of that to group. Used like this:

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE condition GROUP BY DATE(datefield)
```